# Problem when renaming a files in a foor loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, rename, zsh

I want to rename different files:

```
for ((i = 2; i < 10; i++)); mv /Users/neurolab/Desktop/Stephan/Oncology/dummy/sub-$i/ses-1/anat/Sub* /Users/neurolab/Desktop/Stephan/Oncology/dummy/sub-$i/ses-1/anat/sub-$i_ses-1_T1w.nii.gz;
```

But by using $i_ it does not recognize the "$i_ses" part and skips "$i_ses". There is no problem if I use a hyphen such as "$i-ses".

How can I avoid this problem?

Best

Comment: If you rename multiple files in a single `mv` command, the last argument has to be a directory name, not a filename.

Comment: Use `${i}` to delimit the variable.

Comment: You might, in this case, be interested in the 'rename' command

Comment: @DrS : `-`, like `/`, is not a valid part of a variable name and hence **delimits** the name. `_` would be valid as part of  a name and hence does not delimit the name.

Comment: If you are using zsh, take a look at `zmv` for batch file renaming.